# transform file content into array or grep for values

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, grep, associative-array

I have a file containing config information and a shell script that reads that file. I want to hand over values to a bash script.

**file.txt**

```
varNumber=1.1.1
varName=testThis
varFile=~/myDir/mySubDir/output.zip
```

**myShellScript.sh**

```
FILENAME="~/myDir/mySubDir/output.zip" <- this is what I expect from grep/awk
startNextScript.sh -f $FILENAME
```

I would like to extract the variables either as an associated array or - if easier - grep for them,
but as I'm not used to writing commands like this in bash I am asking for help!

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to source that config file?

Comment: Yes, you may ;-) But I'm probably not able to give you a good answer... What's the difference between reading/transforming files/working with variables and sourcing?

Comment: Your `file.txt` already contains variable assignments. If you use `source file.txt` in your script, then those variables will become available to your script.

Answer (score 1):

Using associative array in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A vars
while read -r line ; do
    var=${line%%=*}     # Remove everything after the first =.
    value=${line#*=}    # Remove everything before the first =.
    vars[$var]=$value
done < file.txt

echo Number: ${vars[varNumber]}
echo Name: ${vars[varName]}
echo File: ${vars[varFile]}
```